# Does memory for new have to come from operator new?

Tags: c++, c++11

When considering something along the lines of

```
auto x = new T;
```

Does the Standard enforce that the memory *must* come from `operator new`- class-specific or global? i.e., there is no way a conforming implementation, given a lack of a class-specific `operator new`, could get the memory from anywhere except the global `operator new`?

Comment: If you've used `auto x`, is that because `T* x` is potentially wrong, because `T` is potentially an array type? In which case, is the answer you're looking for that yes, it can come from an `operator new[]` instead of an `operator new`? I'll get me coat.

Comment: no, it's because I'm lazy. The type of T is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have it the wrong way round.

The expression `new T` always consists of two steps:

1. A suitable `operator new` is searched for. If one exists in the class `T`, that one is taken, otherwise the global one is taken. The global one always exists, as this is mandated by the standard (so you can never "define" it (since it is already defined), but you can *replace* it).

   You can say `::new T` to always pick the global `operator new` unconditionally.
2. Once the allocation function has been called and succeeded, the object is constructed in that memory.

If you say `new (a, b, c) T`, then the same happens, only that in step 1 we are now looking for an `operator new` overload with the appropriate signature.

Answer (score 4):

It is not guaranteed to be `::operator new`, as the memory can come from a class specific `operator new` instead, but if no such class-specific version exists, then the global version will be used. The relevant part of the standard is `[expr.new]/8`:

> A new-expression obtains storage for the object by calling an allocation function. ... the allocation function’s name is operator new ...

Comment: So there is absolutely no way a conforming implementation could call anything other than global or class-specific operator new?

Comment: @DeadMG: It seems pretty clear to me: the storage is obtained from an allocation function, and the allocation function is operator new.

Comment: Yes, allocation/deallocation functions names are `operator new/delete/[]` only. Also note that you could override class-specific allocator with `::` to enforce global allocator: `auto x = ::new T;`

Answer (score 4):

> Does the Standard enforce that the memory *must* come from operator new- class-specific or global?

Yes, it does.

`§5.3.4 [expr.new]`:

> p8 A *new-expression* obtains storage for the object by calling an *allocation function* (3.7.4.1). [...] If the allocated type is a non-array type, **the allocation function’s name is `operator new`** [...].
>
> p9 If the *new-expression* begins with a unary `::` operator, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the  global scope. Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or array thereof, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the scope of `T`. If this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a class type, the allocation function’s name is looked up in the global scope.